# Tricky Binary puzzle

Tags: binary

Two numbers, A and B, are stored in one byte floating point notation using the least significant (rightmost) 3 bits for the exponent. Both parts of each number are in 2's complement.

If the A and B are 01000111 and 11101000, then A+B in the same notation as the operands is (Give all 8 bits): __________

Here's what I've worked out so far:

I need to find C, where A + B = C.

The rightmost three digits are the exponents according to the problem, so:

A = 01000^111 
as far as I understand in 2's compliment
01000 = 8 and 111 = -1
thus A = 8^-1

B = 1101^000, any number to the exponent 0 is 1, thus B=1
So A+B = 8^-1 + 1 = 9/8
Now I need to convert 9/8 to a five byte 2's compliment binary base raised to a 3 byte 2's compliment Binary exponent. As far as I'm aware the range for that base is -32 to 31 and the range for the exponent is -3 to 2. No combination in that range is = 9/8. I don't know where or how I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> The rightmost three digits are the exponents according to the problem, so: A = 01000^111 as far as I understand in 2's compliment 01000 = 8 and 111 = -1 thus A = 8^-1 B = 1101^000, any number to the exponent 0 is 1

You are incorrect, the representation is

```
A = b01000 * 10^b111 = 8 * 10^-1 = 8 * 0.1 = 0.8
B = b11101 * 10^b000 = -3 * 10^0 = -3 * 1 = -3
```

When they say "exponent" they mean the exponent of the `* 10^x` of the number to find how far to the left or right you need to shift the decimal point.

So A + B = C would be `0.8 - 3 = -2.2`. You now need to translate -2.2 in to the notation which I will leave as a exercise for you.

Comment: So, to represent -2.2 in this notation I would need -22 (11010) raised to an exponent that is of base 10 and will result in the decimal sliding once to the left, ie 10 ^ -1 (111) for a final result of 11010111
Does this look correct? Thank you by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we got this one wrong, here's the answer given after the fact.

Note that you cannot add two floating point numbers in the usual way before ensuring that their exponents are the same.
A = 8 * 2^-1 = 4.
B = -3 * 2^0 = -3.
Change A to 4 * 2^0 (
Change the first number to 4 * 2^0 (00100000). Then you can add them to get 7 * 2^0
Change the first number to 00100000 (which is 001000000). Now you can add the two giving
00100000 (=  4 * 2^0)+11101000 (= -3 * 2^0)=00001000 (=  1 * 2^0)